# Why build in teamcity is still success even if checkout of git fails with error 128 in Teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity, checkout

I have a teamcity build which ends green (success) even if the first step of checking out git repo fails with an error 128.

Is there something I am missing or is there a way to configure so that build fails for a failed checkout ?

Comment: Check your "Failure Conditions". Also, note later steps can be configured to run only if previous steps succeeded, or regardless.

Comment: Good tips but I dont seem to find a relevant configuration there. The build step is last in the series.  Now I noticed, the custom script (its a python build script) ends with a "Build FAILED" status and Teamcity still turns it green. I am surely missing something basic.

Comment: The "Failure Conditions" setting is part of the main build configuration (left side) below the Build Steps. As for the "Build FAILED" message, perhaps the script just needs to return a non-zero code in that case too?